# Evaluating $\int{e^{x^{1/3}}dx}$

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

How can I get  $$\int{e^{x^{1/3}}dx}$$
I think integrating by parts may work, but I can't figure out the exact way.

Comment: Substitute, $x = t^3$ for example.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Math.SE. Please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/title-and-latex). Also, I have changed the formatting of the title so as to make it take up less vertical space -- this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions. See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In addition to what @Lord_Farin said, keeping titles as short as possible is also a good practice, as they end up as related links on right hand side, in this case it is evident that the integral is indefinite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\int e^{x^{1/3}} dx \stackrel{x=t^3}{=} 3\int t^2 e^t dt \stackrel{(*)}{=} 3 (t^2 - 2t + 2) e^t + C \stackrel{t=x^\frac{1}{3}}= 2(x^\frac{2}{3} - 2x^\frac{1}{3} + 2) e^{x^\frac{1}{3}} + C$$

$(*)$: We see $$(t^2 e^t)' = (t^2 + 2t) e^t$$
And iterate
$$\begin{align*}
((t^2 - 2t)e^t)' & = (t^2 + 2t - 2t - 2)e^t \\
((t^2 - 2t + 2) e^t)' & = (t^2 + 2t - 2t - 2 + 2)e^t = t^2 e^t
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Interesting that $\int \exp(x^{1/3}) dx$ is elementary, but $\int \exp(x^{2/3}) dx$ is not.

Comment: A natural question then, which Liouville probably knew the answer to, is for which integers $a$ and $b$ can $\exp(x^{a/b})$ be integrated.

Comment: That's a great question @martycohen, what's the answer? :)

Answer (score 1):

another solution :

$$ x = t^3 \Rightarrow $$

then we have to evaluate

$$ I = \int t^2 e^t \ dt $$

$$ u = t^2 \quad , dv = e^t \ dt $$

$$ du = 2t \ dt \quad , v = e^t $$

$$ \Rightarrow I = uv - \int v \ du = t^2 e^t - 2\int te^t \ dt $$

again $$ u  = t \quad , dv = e^t \ dt $$

$$ du = dt \quad , v = e^t $$

$$ \Rightarrow I = t^2 e^t - 2\left( te^t - \int e^t \ dt \right) = t^2e^t -  2te^t + e^t + C  $$

if you don't know integrating by parts :

$$ d(uv) = u \ dv + v \ du $$

$$ \Rightarrow \int d(uv) = \int u \ dv + \int v \ du $$

$$ \Rightarrow uv = \int u \ dv + \int v \ du  \Rightarrow \int u \ dv = uv -  \int v \ du $$

:-)